# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name- Command Prompt

Tags: java, selenium, jar

I have a Project called **OneRepots** and that file i exported and put it in the directory `C:\jars>`
In the Jars folder i have

- OneReports.jar
- testng.jar
- TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java
- Test.XML

The `OneReports.jar` i have exported from eclipse and it contains few java Projects.

The `Test.xml` i have created testsuite and that file is

```
files.add("C:\\Documents and Settings\\amth\\workspace\\OneReports\\src\\test.xml");
```

I have `common.io`, log and selenium jar files in the directory `C:\Program Files\Java\selenium`.

Then in command prompt i tried to execute. The error getting as follows:

```
C:\Jars>javac -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\selenium\*.jar";"OneReports.jar";"testng.jar" testngTestSuiteUsingXML.java
C:\Jars>java testngTestSuiteUsingXML
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: testngTestSuiteUsingXML (wrong name: test/TestngTestSuiteUsingXML)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: (And many, many others.) It's not really clear that this has much to do with Android, mind you.

Comment: when you run java you will also need to specify the classpath

Comment: so ur testcase testngTestSuiteUsingXML exist in test package ??

Comment: @Niks Tyagi which package are you asking.

Comment: wrong name: test/TestngTestSuiteUsingXML so testcase exist in any package ?? mean have you specify package for it

Comment: In OneReports.jar the TestngTestSuiteUsingXML is existing because i exported from eclipse

Comment: The class TestngTestSuiteUsingXML exist in jar ??

Comment: yes in this directory i have the entire projects whatever working in eclipse. C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\test

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48541/discussion-between-amir-and-niks-tyagi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The testcase `testngTestSuiteUsingXML` exist in the package `test` so while running the .class you need to specify the package too.Use below cmd :

```
    java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\selenium*.jar";"OneReports.jar";"testng. 
jar" test.TestngTestSuiteUsingXML
```